# Beautiful Soup で 5GB のファイルを読み取り中、killed と表示されてしまう

Tags: python, python3, xml, beautifulsoup

5GBのxmlファイルを読み取り,soup-containsで1万行辺りのテキストファイルの数値がarticle-id_pmidだったら特定の文字列を含んだparagraphのテキストを抽出するというプログラムがあります.

このプログラムではBeautiful Soupを用いてテキストを抽出しているのですが、それだとkilledと表示されてしまい、メモリ不足ではないかと思い、1.xmlのような形に分割処理をしたいでのすが、可能なのでしょうか.

**ソースコード**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#xmlファイル読み込み
with open('1.xml','r',encoding='utf-8') as xml:      
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

# IDが書かれたテキストファイルを改行コードで区切る
with open('1.txt') as b:
  nums =[n.strip() for n in b.readlines()]
b.close()

nums= ','.join(f'"{n}"' for n in nums)

texts = soup.select(f'''
    document:has(>passage >infon[key="article-id_pmid"]:-soup-contains({nums})) >
        passage >
            infon[key="type"]:-soup-contains("paragraph") ~ text:-soup-contains("first") 
''')
text = [t.text for t in texts]
   
xml.close()

#実行結果を指定のファイルに保存
with open ('2.txt','w')as txt:
  print(text,file=txt)
txt.close
```

#### 1.xml

```
    <collection>
        <document>
            <passage>
                <infon key="article-id_pmid">1111</infon>
            </passage>
            <passage>
                <infon key="type">paragraph</infon>
                <text>which was first diagnosed in Wuhan. </text>
            </passage>
        </document>
   <collection>
```

Comment: 実メモリはどの程度積んでいるのかも念のため追記してみてください。

Comment: `with open(...) as XXX:`している`xml`, `b`, `txt`をわざわざ`.close()`していますが、それは不要では？[Pythonで開いたファイルのクローズを忘れやすい人のためのwith文の使い方](https://tonari-it.com/python-with-file-open-close/) そしてこの記事のように表示されたメッセージを略さずに提示してみてください。[What does 'killed' mean when processing a huge CSV with Python, which suddenly stops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19189522/9014308) あと明示的にガベージコレクトしてみてはどうでしょう？[【Python】メモリ開放でパフォーマンスを向上させる方法](https://myafu-python.com/knowledge/memory/)

Comment: `:-soup-contains()`は負荷の高い操作なので, それ無しで行ってみるとなにか違うかも

Comment: XMLファイルを分割して処理するか、もしくは BeautifulSoup の`parse_only` オプションで処理対象の XML entity を限定するなどの対応が考えられます。

Comment: 1.xmlのような形に大きなxmlを編集することは可能なのでしょうか.

Comment: `1.txt` の形式である場合、一旦XMLとしてのパースを考えずに 複数の `passage` として分割すればなんとかなりそうです。

Comment: どういう風に分割すればいいんですかね.簡単な質問ですいません.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://qiita.com/haminiku/items/faa6e4f20b4d94896834
こちらのサイトにまさにやりたいことがのってるのでは？

とりあえずメモリ問題を解決するだけで
2.txt への書き込みはそのままなのでやりたいことができてるかは不明ですが

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# 参考：https://qiita.com/haminiku/items/faa6e4f20b4d94896834

def file_read_generator(file_path, start, end):
    """
    XMLをパースして satrt 〜 end を読み込み返却するgenerator
    :rtype: str
    """
    f = open(file_path, 'r')
    count = 0
    txt = ''

    # Fileを1行ずつ読む
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        if start in line:
            txt = ''
        txt += line
        if end in line:
            result = txt
            txt = ''
            yield result

        if count % 1000 == 0:
            print(f'read {count} line')


with open('1.txt') as b:
    # IDが書かれたテキストファイルを改行コードで区切る
    nums =[n.strip() for n in b.readlines()]
nums= ','.join(f'"{n}"' for n in nums)


#実行結果を指定のファイルに保存
with open ('2.txt','w')as txt:
    for body in file_read_generator('1.xml', '<document>', '</document>'):
        # parseする
        soup = BeautifulSoup(body)
        texts = soup.select(f'''
            document:has(>passage >infon[key="article-id_pmid"]:-soup-contains({nums})) >
                passage >
                    infon[key="type"]:-soup-contains("paragraph") ~ text:-soup-contains("first") 
        ''')
        text = [t.text for t in texts]
        print(text,file=txt)
```